# Install vee-validate under vuejs3 I got error

Tags: vee-validate, vuejs3

under vuejs3 I  install vee-validate with command

```
yarn add vee-validate@next
```

and on success I run server and got errors on

```
$ yarn run serve            
yarn run v1.22.5
$ vue-cli-service serve
 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                   
    2:07:01 PM

This dependency was not found:

* vee-validate/dist/rules in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/components/auth/Login.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vee-validate/dist/rules
Error from chokidar (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot): Error: Circular symlink detected: "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/wwwroot" points to "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot"
```

I pasted my code from vuejs 2 app as :

```
<script>
  import { bus } from '../../../src/main'
  import appMixin from '@/appMixin'

  import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, extend } from 'vee-validate'
  import * as rules from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'

  Object.keys(rules).forEach(rule => {
    extend(rule, rules[rule])
  })

  export default {
    name: 'loginPage',
    mixins: [appMixin],

    components: {
      ValidationObserver,
      ValidationProvider
    },
```

But reading here https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate
I do not see if there is some syntax changes for vuejs 3 I have to apply ?

```
package.json:
{
  "name": "yt3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0-0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "mitt": "^2.1.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.4",
    "vee-validate": "^4.0.0-beta.16",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-rc.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  }
}
```

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**
I added line

```
 "vee-validate": "^3.1.0"
```

in package.json file and running command

```
 yarn
```

and

```
 yarn run serve
```

I got error in browser's console:

```
vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:867 Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor
    at eval (vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:867)
    at Module../node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.esm.js (chunk-vendors.js:3389)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/components/auth/Login.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:10)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-
```

looks like vee-validate 3 and vuejs 3 are not compatible?
Which validation tools for vuejs 3 would you advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some comments from issue on Github [Migration Guide for version 4](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/2849):

- *there is no direct upgrade route as the API is completely different*
- *Even letting people know that v4 is for Vue 3 and v3 is for Vue2 is going to be useful for people*

SO: V4 of `vee-validate` is for Vue 3 ONLY and has very different API from V3 (which is for Vue 2 ONLY)

Also from [V4 guide](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/validation) is seems they decided to throw away build-in validators in favor of using specialized library like [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup)

So using any code from existing Vue 2 app doesn't make any sense - If yoou are using Vue 3:

- `vee-validate`: use guide for V4 and write your code again with new API....
- be prepared that **lots** of established libraries **do not have** stable version for Vue 3 yet....that's the reason I'm staying on Vue 2 for at least 6 months for any serious project (while playing with Vue 3 on the side)

Comment: But can I use     "vee-validate": "^3.1.0" which I used under vuejs 2? Are they compatible?

Comment: pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK